# How to change root url for wordpress?

Tags: smarty

I have a Wordpress blog http://www.bestchaga.com/blog/ this sites css and pictures are taken from http://www.sayanhealth.com how can I change this url address to http://www.bestchaga.com?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I got answer it is in wp-options table.
Why minus? U better answer, its not difficult!

Comment: Actually a little googling could have solved your problem. Just like it did right now. There wasn't any need to post that question. I am damn sure that it already would have been answered on various forums. That can be the reason of one down vote.